# NGINX Not Logging to Syslog

Tags: nginx, syslog

We are using nc to listen to a port:

```
nc -kluvw 0 localhost 9000
```

Using nc to send a message:

```
echo "hi" | nc -u localhost 9000
```

This will print "Hi" on the server.

However, when setting up the access log as a syslog logger it won't log anything.  Logging to /dev/stdout works.

Works:

```
access_log /dev/stdout l2met;
```

Doesn't work:

```
access_log syslog:server=localhost:9000 l2met;
```

Comment: What's your nginx version?

Comment: In your `/etc/syslog.conf`, what file (and severity filtering) to you have configured for these `local7` facility logs?  I.e. could syslog be filtering out the (default) info-level `access_log` messages (or ignoring the `local7` facility), and if so, would adding the `severity=` or `facility=` [nginx syslog parameters](http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html) help?

Comment: I have a newer nginx.  I got it working, but am unclear why it works now.  I wasn't using syslog.  I was trying to verify that nginx was sending data to a  listening UDP port.  See the nc command at the start of the question?  Was doing a sanity check since I couldn't see the output with syslog.

Comment: Which syslog do you use? please can you share the syslog config. can you try to set facility=daemon and see if in the daemon log are some nginx log entry?

Comment: I'm using nc there is no syslog config.  Was trying to verify data shows up.